# Separation of convexity on uniquely geodesic space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

A metric $d: X \times X \to [0,\infty)$
is said to be *intrinsic* provided that the distance between any two points is the infimum of the lengths of
paths joining the points. A space is an *inner metric space* when it is equipped with an intrinsic metric.
A *geodesic segment*, or simply *segment*, is an isometry  of an interval $[a,b] \to X$.

Assume $(X,d)$ satisfies the following three conditions

1. $X$ is a locally compact complete inner metric space,
2. Any pair of distinct points in $X$ can be joined by a geodesic segment,
3. For any point $p \in X$, there exists a radius $r>0$ such that for any distinct points $x,y$ in a closed metric ball $B(p;r)$ can be joined by a unique shortest geodesic segment in $X$.

> **Question.** Assume that $X$ has finite covering dimension $n\geq 3$. Does there exist a codimension-one subset $S \subset X$ containing point $p$ such that for any distinct points $x,y \in B(p;r)\cap S$ can be joined by a unique shortest geodesic segment in $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" even if $X$ is a generic [Hadamard manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_manifold).
In this case, the conditions 1 a 2 hold automatically.

The set $S$ is a locally geodesic hypersurface in $X$ and it is known that generic Riemannian manifold does not admit such surfaces.
Check Corollary 1.4 in our ["About every convex..."](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189) and the references therein.